# Hide tkinter Text widget border

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm building a text editor with Python 3.7 and tkinter Text widget. I would like to have a flat display and hide the borders around the text widget (not even focus border). The Text widget is initialized with `db=0` config. However - I'm getting it work as expected on my Windows 10 machine but border is still showing on Linux (Ubunto 19.04). Is there a way to hide the black border on Linux?

This is how the widget is set:

```
self.editor_text = tk.Text(self.editor_frame, bd=0, bg="white", fg="black", font=(self.FONT_NAME, self.FONT_SIZE), undo=True, autoseparators=True, maxundo=-1)
```

This is how it looks on Ubunto (I highlighted the border in yellow background):

[image]

This is how the same code works on Windows 10 (which is how I'd like it to show on Linux as well):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to isn't a border *per se*. It's called a highlight ring and it is used to let the user know that the text widget has focus.

If you want to remove it, set `highlightthickness` to zero.

Comment: Ive noticed for me the bottom and right border\highlight thickness are missing on all the text fields I add, is this by design?

Comment: @berimbolo: I've never seen this or heard anyone mention it before.

Comment: I will start a new post and add screen shots.

Answer (score 3):

```
self.editor_text = tk.Text(self.editor_frame, bd=0, bg="white", fg="black", highlightthickness = 0, borderwidth=0, font=(self.FONT_NAME, self.FONT_SIZE), undo=True, autoseparators=True, maxundo=-1)
```

if it not solved try to do `self.editor_text = tk.Text(self.editor_frame, bd=0, bg="white", fg="black", font=(self.FONT_NAME, self.FONT_SIZE), undo=True, autoseparators=True, maxundo=-1)`

```
self.editor_text.config(highlightthickness = 0, borderwidth=0)
```